# Inkscape: scale with keep aspect ratio as default?

Tags: inkscape, scale

I know that I can keep aspect ratio when scaling images by pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

But I really don't like this default.

Is there a way to modify inkscape, to make scale and keeping aspect ratio the default?

I created an issue: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/issues/1375

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the icon "lock"! However, the mouse's movement in Inkscape is very nervous, almost impossible to get the accuracy I want. Is not there a trick to reduce?
Pär.L

Comment: @PärLundqvist why don't you ask this on this site as a new question? I don't know the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're adding a bounty on a question that is almost four years old and you've accepted the answer??

Comment: Since I think the sane default is not here yet.

Comment: If you placed a bounty on this to try and get more answers, you might want to unselect the chosen answer. People, in general, may not even bother with answering if they see an answer has already been marked "correct".

Comment: It is curious how Inkscape and OpenOffice Draw both have exactly the same problem. Photographs in particular must have a fixed aspect ratio to look right, and any image editor ought to fix their aspect ratio by default, in either program.

Comment: @DavidSpector I guess Inkscape does not have a product owner who cares for the needs of the first time users.

Comment: I think Inkscape is open software. It is certainly very old. Old software frequently is not maintained anymore, due to being poorly written. Anyone know of modern free software for editing SVGs?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

When scaling an object with the mouse by dragging the corner handles it is quite handy to lock the aspect ration to preserve it. This is done with a small lock symbol in the top panel:

[image: Inkscape 1.02]

[image]

Comment: This works great for one session! But it is not preserved when inkscape is restarted. Is there any possibility to keep this behavior across restarts?

Comment: This does not realy answer the question. The question was to make "keep aspect ratio the default".

Comment: I can't find this small lock. Can you give a screenshot? Thank you.

Comment: @cyj: see edit for an alternative shot from recent Inkscape 1.02

Comment: It is literally the smallest lock I have ever seen. I hope Inkscape can make it look more noticable.

Comment: The lock doesn't work if you drag the right-hand edge of a photograph. Dragging to the left causes the image to be squeezed unacceptably.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Inkscape doesn't support settings like this to be embedded in default templates.

A couple work arounds are to just hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while dragging the corners.

Or, once you create an object and lock proportions any new object you create will automatically have its proportions already locked.

[image]

Comment: I want a sane default: Lock proportions by default and this setting should survive a restart of inkscape. I want to set this once and forever.

Comment: @guettli Well that's not really possible unfortunately until they update the software.

Personally I see nothing wrong with just holding down the ctrl key when scaling.

Comment: @Overyraptor for me this is not a solution. I would buy a commercial software which works on linux, if there would be one.

Comment: @guettli "Lock proportions by default and this setting should survive a restart of inkscape. I want to set this once and forever." Have you tried reporting it to the authors of the software (after checking whatever it was maybe rejected for some reason)? See https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/issues

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny good point. I created an issue: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/issues/1375